# Video swap with hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I've been trying to do a video swap for a site I'm working on. I want to change the bigger image for the one I hover over.  I'm able to do the image swap but when I try to add video it falls apart. Anyone know what I can do?

```
<div id="imgDetail">
   <video width="546" height="362" controls>
<source src="assets/img/ebuzzing3" type="video/mp4" class="img-responsive"  id="bigImg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
<ul>
       <li><video width="320" height="240" controls>
     <source src="assets/img/ebuzzing3" type="video/mp4" class="img-responsive" id="bigImg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video></li>
       <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing1.png" class="thumb" /></li>
       <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing2.png"  class="thumb" /></li>
       <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing3.png" class="thumb" /></li>
       <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing4.png"  class="thumb" /></li>
       <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing5.png" class="thumb" /></li>
       <li><img src="assets/img/ebuzzing6.png"  class="thumb" /></li>
    </ul>
 </div>



$('#imgDetail li img').hover(function(){
        $('#bigImg').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, this could help:

HTML

```
<div id="imgDetail">
    <video width="546" height="362" controls id="video">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" class="img-responsive" id="bigImg">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
    <ul>
        <li  ><img data-source='http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4' src="http://placehold.it/100x100" > </li>
        <li  ><img data-source='http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4' src="http://placehold.it/100x100" ></li>
          <li  ><video data-source='http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4' width="100" height="100" controls>
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" class="img-responsive" id="bigImg">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#imgDetail img,video').on("mouseover", function () {



    $('#video').attr('src', $(this).data('source'));

});
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/6fU76/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/6fU76/1/)

I am not sure do you want small video as thumbnail for bigger one, or ordinary image thumbnail... so, both options are there. I have used custom data attributes, because of flexibility...

Edit: updated fiddle:
**http://jsfiddle.net/6fU76/7/**

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank-you! I'm trying to swap between both videos and regular images, replicating something like this https://angel.co/payward-kraken. Do you know how I can go about making it work for both?

Comment: @AnaIsabel, np, see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6fU76/7/ modify it to your needs... if image is first element, should be hidden, and vice versa...